# How to Validate a template using Heat API Client?

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

Unable to Validate a template using Heat-API client,when used below method

```
   from heatclient.client import Client  
   heat = Client('1', endpoint=heat_url, token=auth_token)  
   heat.stacks.validate(template_file)
```

Error mesage:

```
 TypeError: validate() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the source code for heat client api:

```html
def validate(self, **kwargs):
        """Validate a stack template."""
        resp, body = self.client.json_request('POST', '/validate', data=kwargs)
        return body
```

So, you should not put any argument in the validate() function and I would try run: heat.stacks.validate() and see what it gives you

[source code](https://github.com/openstack/python-heatclient/blob/master/heatclient/v1/stacks.py)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
heat.stacks.validate(template=template_file)
```

OR

```
heat.stacks.validate(template=template_file["template"])
#If your template is an inner dict
```